# Accessing GeoServer WFS services in ArcGIS Online map viewer?

Tags: geoserver, wms, wfs, arcgis-online

Has anyone was able to add GeoServer WFS service into ArcGIS Online map viewer? By this I mean having an ArcGIS Online account (either free or for Organizations), logging in and [adding layers from the web](http://www.arcgis.com/home/webmap/viewer.html?useExisting=1).

I have no problems adding a WMS service such as this one
http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=1.0.0&request=getfeature&typename=topp%3astates. It is being retrieved and drawn nicely in ArcGIS Online map viewer.

What about the WFS services? When trying to add this service (which should be a WFS?) http://suite.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs?service=wfs&version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typename=usa:states&featureid=states.23, I am getting only images (somehow "redirected" to WMS maybe?). OGC things are not really my strongest skills.

Is it possible to get raw vector data (served by GeoServer) instead of map images into the ArcGIS Online map viewer? Any workarounds to get it from GeoServer via some other source into ArcGIS Online?

Comment: I tried several methods a month or so back to do this and was unable to. I would be very interested in a solution for this but last I heard it was not supported. You may have already seen [this question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/64383/is-it-possible-to-make-ogc-wms-wfs-look-like-a-arcgis-server-layer-including-fu) or [this thread](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/50597) both make it seem that it is not possible at this time but maybe later this year.

Comment: Thanks Chris, the geonet page includes the info that Esri is working on that - they have plans https://geonet.esri.com/message/457449#457449. You could make an answer, I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would seem that at this time WFS is not supported within the ArcGIS Online viewer. However this functionality may be added in the future, possibly as soon as Fall 2015. According to a [post](https://geonet.esri.com/message/457449#457449) on [this](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/50597) geonet thread:

> There are plans to provide WFS support within the map viewer. We are
> looking at different options, and it may be late 2015 by the time we
> can support this. At this time, we are looking at possible options.
> Sorry, I cannot provide more specifics at this time.

Also attempting to wrap a [WFS feature as a ArcGIS feature layer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/64383/is-it-possible-to-make-ogc-wms-wfs-look-like-a-arcgis-server-layer-including-fu) is difficult. As far as I know only a hosted feature layer/ArcGIS server will support WFS like functionality (creating, deleting, and editing features). I'm not sure what your specific needs are but I was able to sign up for a [free ArcGIS developers account](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/plans/) (this comes with 50 credits a month) and was able to upload and host my feature layer for free. Once the feature layer was created I could add it to the map viewer and have WFS like functionality.

Note: I dont work for or represent Esri. My suggestions are simply based on prior experience and workarounds.

Comment: I suspect ESRI are taking their time supporting WFS in the map viewer to encourage people to host data in ArcGIS Online itself or with ArcGIS Server.. once they open the gates to using Geoserver WFS directly with AGOL it will remove another reason to use ArcGIS Server to host feature services.

Answer (score 1):

At this time, with the last update, WFS is supported within the ArcGIS Online viewer - july 09, 2016