# How to query WFS layer in ArcGIS Online?

Tags: wfs, arcgis-online, query

I want to incorporate the following WFS query URL in ArcGIS Online:

```
https://9.9.9.9:8080/geoserver/workspace/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=workspace:education&filter=
<PropertyIsEqualTo><PropertyName>amenity</PropertyName>
<Literal>school</Literal></PropertyIsEqualTo>
```

The query above was tested positively. However when adding that to ArcGIS Online the URL requires to be shortened down to 'GetFeature', the layer selection happens via dropdown menu and supposedly the query part goes into 'Add Parameters' doesn't it?

```
Parameter = filter
Value = <PropertyIsEqualTo><PropertyName>amenity</PropertyName>
    <Literal>school</Literal></PropertyIsEqualTo>
```

I also tried to add the workspace/layer declaration as parameter to no avail. The Parameters appear to be ignored because all the GML is parsed unfiltered.
What am I missing here?

Note: The answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/162277/accessing-geoserver-wfs-services-in-arcgis-online-map-viewer) suggests to tediously sign up to an ESRI developer account but that seems to be from a time where WFS wasen't supported at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a WFS service provided by a ArcGIS Server, you can add the WFS layer to a web map in AGOL and then filter the data through the layer properties buttons. It automatically recognizes available fields for you to construct your filter criteria.

After applying the filter you can save it as a map layer in your AGOL account in order to use it with others maps.

Comment: Don't get me wrong but what layer properties buttons are you referring to? After having added a WFS layer it offers me a context menu with several options. One of these is 'WFS OGC Options' where I can add said parameters. All the others are not related to filtering data at all.

Comment: I was testing with a WFS service provided by a ArcGIS Server and, apparently, it behaves differently from a WFS service provided by other map servers.

 I then tested with a WFS service from another source and I also had only the 'WFS OGC Options' you mention.

I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Since we're now talking about the same thing do you concur with my estimation that the 'WFS OGC Options' are supposed to parse the query to the server?

Comment: The tests I've made in order to set filters to the OGC WFS data had no success, but I found this doc that talks about the parameter setting: https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-online/mapping/improved-ogc-client-capabilities-using-custom-parameters-september-2016/